# How to Adjust the Alignment in Hints

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, hint

Not sure where to add, the hints on the app is cover by the input design.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="350dp" //match_parent or wrap_content produce same issue
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/select_product_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/input_design"
    android:hint="Product Name..." />
```

[The Issues of the Hints in the Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYGFP.png)

Comment: The input design code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<stroke
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:width="3dp"
    />

    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>

Comment: Sorry just found out need to add android:padding="20dp"

Answer (score 0):

you can use TextInputLayout:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/enough_margin"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_Login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="product name . . ."
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/material_blue_500"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

add to style.xml :

```
 <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Just found out need to add android:padding="20dp" Thanks for sharing